# Mostrar mensaje usuario y/o contraseña incorrecta

Tags: php, html

Buen día, ¿como hago para mostrar un mensaje que me diga USUARIO Y/O CONTRASEÑA INVÁLIDA cuando la persona digite mal el usuario, mal la contraseña, o en su defecto mal tanto usuario como contraseña?

Este es el login.php (donde está el formulario)

```
 <title>LOGIN</title>
 <h2>Por favor ingrese su usuario y contraseña</h2>
 <form method="post" action="manejador.php">
 <input type="text" name="user" placeholder="Usuario" required autofocus>
 <br><br>
 <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Contraseña" required>
 <br><br>
 <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Ingresar">
 </form>
```

Y este es el código (manejador.php) que me valida la información, y de ser ser verdadera me lleva a una página requerida

```
 <?php
 session_start();

 if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
 $username = "julian";
 $password = "123abc";

 if ((isset($_POST['user'])) || (isset($_POST['password']))){

    $nombre = $_POST['user'];
    $pass = $_POST['password'];

    if (($nombre == $username) && ($pass == $password)){
        $_SESSION['username'] = $nombre;
        header("location: busqueda.php");

    }else{
        header("location: login.php");
    }

 }else{
    header("location: login.php");
 }

 } else{
 header("location: login.php");
 }

 ?>
```

Agradezco de antemano cualquier ayuda !

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Agregale un parametro que indique el login ha fallado al momento de redireccionar al login.php:

```
//...
else{
  header("location: login.php?fallo=true");
}

//...
```

Entonces en `login.php` verficias si hay un parametro `fallo` con el valor `true` en el query de la url utilizando `$_GET`:

```
<title>LOGIN</title>

<h2>Por favor ingrese su usuario y contraseña</h2>
<form method="post" action="manejador.php">
   <input type="text" name="user" placeholder="Usuario" required autofocus>
   <br><br>
   <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Contraseña" required>
   <br><br>
   <?php
       if(isset($_GET["fallo"]) && $_GET["fallo"] == 'true')
       {
          echo "<div style='color:red'>Usuario o contraseña invalido </div>";
       }
     ?>
   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Ingresar">
</form>
```

Comment: Claro y conciso, funcionó como quería, mil gracias hermano !

Comment: Cierto, muy clara y funcional tu ayuda.
Gracias